# How would I apply a transition to a State Machine field?

Tags: 8

I am trying to transition a `state_machine` field on the `User` entity during an event. What I have thus far is:

```
/* @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
$user = User::load($id);

/* @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface $state_field */
$state_field = $user->get('field_screening_status');

/* @var \Drupal\state_machine\Plugin\Field\FieldType\StateItemInterface $state */
$state = $state_field->get(0);

$transitions = $state->getTransitions();

$state->applyTransition($transitions['mark_needs_screening']);
```

Of course, this does not actually save it to the user. I would actually need to call:

```
$user->set('field_screening_status', 'needs_screening');
$user->save();
```

But, how might I instead use the `state_machine` API to apply the transition to a user field?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up with. Would be curious if the community has a better solution.

```
/* @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser());

/* @var \Drupal\state_machine\Plugin\Field\FieldType\StateItemInterface $state */
$state = $user->get('field_screening_status')->get(0);

$transitions = $state->getTransitions();

if (array_key_exists('mark_needs_screening', $transitions)) {
  $user->set('field_screening_status', 'needs_screening');
  $user->save();
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks to @lisastreeter in #commerce on drupal.slack.com

```
$user = User::load($id);
$state = $user->get('field_screening_status')->first();
$transition = $state->getWorkflow()->getTransition('mark_needs_screening');

if ($transition) {
  $state->applyTransition($transition);
}
```

Not sure if that `get(0)` change to `first()` really made the difference, but it works now.